# Scheduling a bunch of tweets at regular intervals

Tags: twitter

I'd like to schedule a big load of tweets so that they go one after the other at regular intervals (say, about 2 hours). I've seen some sites (like [twuffer.com](http://twuffer.com)) that allow you to schedule tweets, but it must be done one by one. This is not feasible for my project, I need something more "batch-like".

Ideally what I'm searching for is a site where I can upload (say) a google docs or excel spreadsheet with the texts and desired post dates of all the tweets.

Do you know if anything like that exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it out, but maybe this [twitter command line client](https://launchpad.net/twitter-cmdline/) can help you do the trick

Comment: Yes but this is a standalone application. I am looking for a webapp, if possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does this work now? I think it doesn't use OAuth so it probably does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Twaiter](http://www.twaitter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Pluggio](http://pluggio.com/) should be able to do what you need but only for RSS feeds as far as I know.
If you can create a feed of what you want, should work great.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with an [iMacros](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox) macro that sends the tweets via the web interface. Then start it  via [task scheduler/command line](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support).